# Regex select all <br/> tags within another html tag

Tags: regex

I adopted some code from another project and it's messed up. I want to select (and eventually remove) all `<br/>` tags but only those **inside** `<pre>` tags. Is there a regex for this?

```
These 2 lines should not be<br/>
touched. Example only.<br/><br/>

<pre class="code">mysql&gt;
<strong> SELECT state, COUNT(*) FROM president GROUP BY state;</strong><br/>
+-------+----------+<br/>
| state | COUNT(*) |<br/>
+-------+----------+<br/>
| OH    |        7 |<br/>
| PA    |        1 |<br/>
| SC    |        1 |<br/>
| TX    |        2 |<br/>
| VA    |        8 |<br/>
| VT    |        2 |
+-------+----------+</pre>
```

Comment: "Regex" means different things depending on the language or tool. In particular, there is no language-agnostic concept of "selecting" or "removing" using regex (though of course many languages and tools offer regex-based mechanisms for doing those things).

Comment: What is the tool that you are using to process the text?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention the tool, I will just assume that your regex engine supports `\G`<sup>1</sup>. Note that this is raw regex and you may need to do some escaping:

```
((?:<pre|\G(?!^))(?:(?!</pre|<\s*/?\s*br)[/s/S])*)<\s*/?\s*br\s*/?\s*>
```

Replacement: `$1`

***An important assumption is that there cannot be (valid) nested `pre` tag in your input.***

[**Demo**](http://www.regex101.com/r/gS1dR8). (Note: The demo might have slightly different regex due to escaping).

`((?:<pre|\G(?!^))(?:(?!</pre|<\s*/?\s*br)[/s/S])*)` this part searches for the beginning of `pre` tag, or continue from last match (where a `br` tag inside `pre` is found), then grab all character until it hits a valid closing `pre` tag (and have to skip ahead - since the next part of the regex matches a `br` tag) or a `br` tag. The `(?!^)` after `\G` is a heuristic to make sure `\G` is only matchable after it is inside a `pre` tag, otherwise, it will also match the start of the input.

A valid tag should not have space between the `<` and tag name for an opening tag, and should not have space between `<`, `/` and tag name for a closing tag. [Reference](http://www.jelks.nu/XML/xmlebnf.html). This fact is applied to check the boundary of a `pre` tag (`pre` tag only ends if a valid closing tag is found). However, the code will match any tag that *looks like* a `br` tag (may not be valid according to the syntax described above) and remove them.

This is the portion that matches the `br` tag: `<\s*\/?\s*br\s*\/?\s*>`. As you can see, it will match even bad tags such as `< /br>` or `</ br>` or `< br>` or `</br/>`. I assume that you don't mind these case being cleaned up.

**Footnote**

1. If the engine supports `\G` last match boundary, then it should also have support other features that I used in this regex such as negative look-ahead `(?!pattern)`.